# gcloud vm Instance is blocking inbound request from my external domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, gcloud

i have a aspnet core app listenning in port 5000 of my gcloud vm instance.
My problem is that whith the code bellow i can make successfull a c# httpclient post within my local computer.
But when i publish it in a other hosting service (webwiz.net) gcloud reject all request with a timeout exception.
this is my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(client_id)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(client_secret)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(grant_type)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(scope))
            });
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage origin_compte_check =  client.PostAsync(new Uri(onj.url + "/connect/token"), content).Result;
var sdsd  = origin_compte_check.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

And the exception:

> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext()

I remark that all outbound request from my gcloud VM instance to my external domain work but inverse dont work.

Comment: Did you open the port in firewall of gcloud VM?

Comment: Yes the port are open and i can acces througth nagivator and also througth c# httpclient from my local computer but only block for c# httpclient from production (webwiz.net hosting)